# How to prevent repetition of the same number with Random.Range?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a function that produce random number at certain range, i use it for spawning object using array index, but i confused when i instatiate 3 object sometimes 2 object are same, it's mean there are 2 same number on different array. i wan to check its already saved in array or not. can you guys help me ? , Thanks

```
void buatobjek (){

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        buatrandom = Random.Range (0, jumlahrandom);
        simpannomorobject [i] = buatrandom;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the array already contains the numbers, if so generate another number, keep doing it as long as the number is present:

```
var number = Random.Range(0, jumlahrandom);

while(simpannomorobject.Contains(number))
{
    number = Random.Range(0, jumlahrandom);
}

simpannomorobject[i] = number;
```